# OpenVPN won't connect from remote location

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding

I set up OpenVPN on a linux machine in my basement.

I'm able to connect from my Windows 8.1 machine without an issue when I'm connected to the local network.

In this instance, I set the config file to use `remote 192.168.0.111 1194`

When I leave my local network, I alter that config file to say: `remote 63.xxx.x.xxx 1194`
Where `63.xxx.xx.xx` is my public IP.

When I'm outside of my local network, I can't connect. Here is my log entry from my latest attempt to connect from an outside network.

```
Mon Oct 06 13:59:54 2014 OpenVPN 2.3.4 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May  2 2014
Mon Oct 06 13:59:54 2014 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014, LZO 2.05
Mon Oct 06 13:59:54 2014 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Mon Oct 06 13:59:54 2014 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]63.xxx.xx.xx:1194
Mon Oct 06 13:59:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1412625595,WAIT,,,
Mon Oct 06 14:00:55 2014 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Oct 06 14:00:55 2014 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Oct 06 14:00:55 2014 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Oct 06 14:00:55 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1412625655,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,
Mon Oct 06 14:00:55 2014 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Mon Oct 06 14:00:57 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Mon Oct 06 14:00:57 2014 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Oct 06 14:00:57 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]63.xxx.xx.xx:1194
Mon Oct 06 14:00:57 2014 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1412625657,WAIT,,,
```

[It seems that it might be a firewall issue](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/253-tls-error-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds-check-your-network-connectivity.html), but I've gone through each of the bullet points on that page again and again and can't find any issues.

> - A perimeter firewall on the server's network is filtering out    incoming OpenVPN packets (by default OpenVPN uses UDP or TCP port
>     number 1194).

I've checked and double checked the router setup, and port 1194 should definitely be forwarded to my linux box... Here's my router's iptables config:

```
 > iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
drop       all  --  anywhere             63.xxx.xx.xx
ACCEPT     2    --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:telnet
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:44401
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:49431
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:tftp
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:1900
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:37000
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:38000
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:5098:5100
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:50032
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:54008
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:500
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT    !esp  --  anywhere             anywhere            MARK match 0x10000000/0x10000000
ACCEPT    !ah   --  anywhere             anywhere            MARK match 0x10000000/0x10000000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:4567
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             224.0.1.60
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       udp dpt:1194
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       tcp dpt:1194
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.17        udp dpt:51490
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.25        udp dpt:53681
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       udp dpt:1194
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       tcp dpt:1194
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       udp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             5.5.126.125         tcp dpt:15979
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.22        udp dpt:16402
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             224.0.0.0/3
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp type 30
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.111       tcp dpt:www
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.18        udp dpt:62558
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.17        udp dpt:57874
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.17        udp dpt:51621
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:58670
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:50209
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:60530
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:60285
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:59415
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:62603
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:52438
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:53919
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:62384
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         tcp dpt:35689
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:35689
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:55287
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:50487
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.3         udp dpt:51697
urlfilter  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST/NONE
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT    !esp  --  anywhere             anywhere            MARK match 0x10000000/0x10000000
ACCEPT    !ah   --  anywhere             anywhere            MARK match 0x10000000/0x10000000
DROP       udp  --  192.168.0.9          anywhere            udp dpt:l2tp
DROP       tcp  --  192.168.0.9          anywhere            tcp dpt:1723
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:5060:5061
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:5060:5061
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
ACCEPT     udp  --  205.171.2.65         anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  205.171.3.65         anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:27167:27169
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:27164:27166
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:27161:27163
drop       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain drop (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `firewall drop: '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain urlfilter (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
SKIPLOG    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
QUEUE      tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
```

It sure seems to me that my router should forward port 1194 to my linux box. I have it also forwarding port 80 without any issue to the same box.

I doubt that my ISP would be blocking port 1194, and not port 80...

> - A software firewall running on the OpenVPN server machine itself is    filtering incoming connections on port 1194. Be aware that many OSes
>     will block incoming connections by default, unless configured
>     otherwise.

I used Yast on my local box to open up port 1194 on the linux machine. I'm pretty sure that this is not the problem, since I can connect to the linux box while connected to my local network. If the linux box's firewall were the issue, I would not be able to connect from a local address, either.

> - A NAT gateway on the server's network does not have a port forward    rule for TCP/UDP 1194 to the internal address of the OpenVPN server
>     machine.

I'm pretty sure that this is configured properly, too, on the router. Here's the iptables nat configuration on the router:

```
 > iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             224.0.0.0/3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:4567
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:51697 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:50487 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:55287 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:35689 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:35689 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:62384 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:53919 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:52438 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:62603 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:59415 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:60285 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:60530 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:50209 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:58670 to:192.168.0.3
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:51621 to:192.168.0.17
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:57874 to:192.168.0.17
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:62558 to:192.168.0.18
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www to:192.168.0.111
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache redir ports 80
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:57106 to:192.168.0.22:16402
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:15980 to:5.5.126.125:15979
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https to:192.168.0.111
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:https to:192.168.0.111
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1194 to:192.168.0.111
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:1194 to:192.168.0.111
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:53681 to:192.168.0.25
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:51490 to:192.168.0.17
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https to:192.168.0.111
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:1194 to:192.168.0.111
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:1194 to:192.168.0.111

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

> - The OpenVPN client config does not have the correct server address in    its config file. The remote directive in the client config file
>     must    point to either the server itself or the public IP address of
>     the    server network's gateway.

I've checked, double checked and triple checked this IP that it's connecting to, and it is correct.

> - Another possible cause is that the windows firewall is blocking    access for the openvpn.exe binary. You may need to whitelist (add it
>     to the "Exceptions" list) it for OpenVPN to work.

I'm fairly certain that this is not the problem because I'm able to connect from my local network. Am I wrong? Does windows 8.1 block the binary when it's connecting to a remote address but not when it's connecting to a local address? This seems highly unlikely to me...

EDIT --

Here's my config file

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client client1

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
;remote 192.168.0.111 1194
remote 63.xxx.xx.xx 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nobody

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client1.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\client1.key"

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo yes

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20

auth-nocache
script-security 2
remote-cert-tls server
```

Does anyone have any other idea why I might have the connection issues I'm having?

EDIT2 -- 
I used this to set up openVPN:
http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:OpenVPN_Installation_and_Setup

There's a section there for "Firewall Configuration" that did not apply to me as I do not have openvz nor kvm. I used yast to open up port 1194 in SuSEfirewall2

Comment: Did you try using another port, e.g. 11940 or anything else? I would not exclude that your provider blocks port 1194. Maybe they don't want VPN servers around...

Comment: no i will give that a shot

Comment: Looks like a firewall (not your firewall but some external) issue to me. Try running it on 443 (if possible). It's an SSL port, so it might be in use on your system, but it's always open.

Comment: @Devator not always but very often. For example my provider actually blocks ONLY this port for incoming connections, because of past security problems with the modems...

Comment: Can you run a tcpdump -p tcp -i your_outer_net_interface -n port 1194 on your router while you are trying to connect? It could show, if the udp packets of your openvpn client arrives to your server. It were the first step.

Comment: I guess your local network in Windows has a Private/Home profile. And when you are outside it's something different, maybe Public. So either try to disable firewall completely or allow OpenVPN connections in a corresponding profile. Maybe that's the case.

Comment: thanks all -- for outer firewall theory blocking 1194 -- i just tried running node.js on 1194 and can access that just fine from an outside network (i can't try to hit openvpn from an outer network right now as i'm not near a remote wifi connection, i used my cellphone to hit 63.xxx.xx.xx:1194 after starting node.js, and i get through as expected on that port, so the problem must be something specific to either the laptop trying to connect, or the openvpn config)

Comment: @PeterHorvath -- I only have access to one network in my office, and it's my local network. Is what you're suggesting going to require that I be connected to a remote network on the laptop while watching the tcp dump on the local router? Is there a way to log that instead so I can do this while I'm not near the router?

Comment: @Glueon that's a good suggestion, I'll give that a shot when I'm out of the office later today

Comment: @tmsimont Yes, you can start a `tcpdump` on the router in a `screen` (either running `screen` on your opensuse and ssh-ing into the router, or on your router).

Comment: my nodejs thoery has one caveat... that was listening on tcp and worked.. perhaps my ISP is blocking the UDP connection to port 1194. i'm gonna switch everything over to tcp, try peter's idea, and then try glueon's idea once i get out to a public network. thanks, all

Comment: @tmsimont No, you shouldn't create "theories", it is not a "theoretic" thing, it is a trivial server debug/hotfix thing and a professional system administrator should be able to handle the situation on a deterministic way, without sacrificing black hens. If you never used `tcpdump` or `screen`, google for them very fast.

Comment: i will have to sacrifice many a black hen until i can get access to an outside network :P

Comment: turns out it was the settings on a specific outside network. all ports other than 80 and 443 are blocked... so i'm using 443 now and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote location was blocking most outbound traffic. I had to run OpenVPN on port 443 (SSL port) to get it to work from the particular location. No remote location would block 443.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your system to forward your gateway traffic:

```
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.ip_forward'
[user@localhost udp]$ sudo !!
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
[sudo] password for user:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
[user@localhost udp]$
```